# Failed to update Android SDK package list (Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

everyone. I worked for my project and in one moment i needed to change API version (23 or 27), i set it in project settings and with Android SDK that i got with editor installation Unity (2020.3.17f1) says that i don't have needed version. After that i updated all API versions, cmdline-tools and some other things via Android Studio SDK Manager and it don't work now (CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.).

Here are all of my errors appearing after trying to build:

1

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Exception in thread "main"

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.
S:\Unity\2020.3.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list

stderr[
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Exception in thread "main"
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunAndroidSdkTool (System.String toolName, System.String arguments, System.Boolean updateCommand, System.String errorMsg, System.String toolsDir, System.String[] warningsToIgnore) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.ListComponentsVersions () (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.UpdatePackagesList () (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.HighestVersionInstalled (UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager+Component tool) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKToolsDetector.GetVersion () (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector.Detect (System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.ProgressHandler onProgress) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector detector) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

3

```
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

4

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <d0e4b8c1204147f3935b6e9c8b8565ad>:0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <d0e4b8c1204147f3935b6e9c8b8565ad>:0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I tried to change SDK folder in Unity Preferences to my Android Studio folder, untick and tick all folders in Preferences, created repositories.cfg in Users\name\ .android, created new fresh project with only changed API version, changed d8.bat to dx.bat and same with .jar files in AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2, changed obsolete to false\true in package.xml (AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools), removed R8 line in Gradle Properties Template file and nothing helped yet.